# CodeBlocks dark theme (not just the editor's theme)

Tags: codeblocks

I want to change my theme in CodeBlocks to dark. And I do not mean just the editor's theme.

I'll show you what I mean:
[image]

I want to change every whitespace to dark. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to invert colors on Windows Settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can get dark mode by default on linux, no luck on windows